# Ubuntu 14.04 + Ncomputing x550 not working

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install x550 ncomputing on ubuntu 14.04. After all updates I tried to install ncomputing x550 device. But while installing dependencies I get error in libqt4-designer. All the dependencies are not installed. I tried to download the latest version of ncomputing but still no success. Please help I am fed up.

Ubuntu version = "ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso"
ncomputing version = "vSpace Server for Linux 3.3.5 with dependencies.zip"

Answer (score 1):

N Computing supports only for < 12.04 Versions.

So , it is better you don't buy N Computing if you want to use ubuntu !!!

Answer (score 0):

first install x550 card to pc and install  ubuntu 14.04.02 and don't update anything download V-space software online suite from N-computing website extract the folder to desktop u get a pdf document read it .Login as root or use the Terminal and login as root  and led path to .sh it will download all the dependencies automatically and vspace soft will install in few min after that reboot it`s work